# Select filter dropdown/pagination with only php

Tags: php, sorting, filter, pagination

I'm new to this site and still fairlu new to PHP so not sure if this is were I need to place my question but here goes. I am currently trying to create a filter for my table using PHP.

The filter options are already in my database; e.g I have a species column which currently contains Snake and Lizard. I have managed to get the options to display in a Dropdown list so when selected it correctly filters either Snake or Lizard, they work and filter correctly however the main problem I have is that when I select the option to progress through the filtered pages using the numbered navigation buttons it clears my filter option and shows everything in the database again. Is it possible to make lock the selection until cleared or another item is selected?

i.e. If I select Lizard from the dropdown is it possible to keep this selection until another option is selected.

Just to clarify, I am using PHP.

`

```
if (!empty($_POST['dropdown']) && $_POST['dropdown'] == 'snake') {

    
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM animal where species = 'snake' and  user = '$username' LIMIT $start_from,".$limit;

    $all_data=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $user_count = mysqli_fetch_row($all_data);   // say total count 9  
    $total_records = $user_count[0];   //9
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);    // 9/3=  3
   

}



else if(!empty($_POST['dropdown']) && $_POST['dropdown'] == 'lizard') {

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM animal where species = 'lizard' and  user = '$username' LIMIT $start_from,".$limit;

    $all_data=mysqli_query($con,$sql);     //added 
    $user_count = mysqli_fetch_row($all_data);   // say total count 9  
    $total_records = $user_count[0];   //9
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);    // 9/3=  3

}


else { //added 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM animal  where user = '$username' LIMIT $start_from,".$limit;  

    $all_data=mysqli_query($con,"select count(*) from animal where user = '$username'");
    $user_count = mysqli_fetch_row($all_data);   // say total count 9  
    $total_records = $user_count[0];   //9
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);    // 9/3=  3

}



$num = 0;


// if($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)){
if($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

       echo "<table>";

 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            if ($num++ % 4== 0 && $num > 1) echo '</tr><tr>';  
 
                 echo "<td>" . $row['animal'] . "</td>";


         // }
            // echo "</tr>";

        }
         // echo "</table>";
  }

}


    $current_page = isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page'] : 1;  

 
    for ($page = $start_page; $page <= $end_page; $page++){
            if ($total_pages > 0) {   

            if ($page == $current_page) {
    
                $active_class = "active";
                   
                 echo"<button class='btn' class='active' a href='room.php?page=".($page)."'>$page</a></button>";
    
    
                 echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            } 
            
    
    
            // else {
                // else if ($num == $limit){
                else if ($num == $limit){
    
                echo '<a href="?page='.$page.'" class="btn">'.$page.'</a>';   
                 
                echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    
        
    
        }
     
     }
    }
     

       echo "<form id='form_id' method='post' name='myform'>";
        echo "<select name='dropdown'>";
    
        // echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";
    
    if($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                  echo "<option name='all'>" . $row['species'] . "</option>";
    
     
        }
         echo "</select>";
         echo "<input id='submit' name='submit' type='submit' value='submit'>";
    
      echo "</form>";
```

`
this is the grab from options display to a page into a table and a filter with pagination

Comment: The original post could use some clarification. It sounds like you are asking how one can have their PHP application make a user selected option persistent. It seems you have multiple options.  However, to noting if you are using any specific framework for the PHP side or for the web frontend side, would help. You can either retain the value as a variable on the PHP side, a variable on the browser side, have the pulldown selection be an ajax call to update the server side, etc. Would need to keep track of unique sessions.

Comment: multiple options would only show if they are in the database. im echoing from that. Not using any ajax currently shall i put my code i have so far? and it filters fine using select from but the select name changes back to the origional. so dropdown list will be:  snake with lizard underneath. click lizard it will show the correct data but the select will say snake again

Comment: Example code would help. From what you said, then when someone selects snake or lizard from the dropdown, the PHP code should take that and update the HTML generated to reflect the option which has been selected.

Comment: yeah because although it displays the results it says snake so will show the snake results if i click previous page. sorry forgot to mention using page numbers. as im new to this site how can i upload code to show you?

Comment: You can usually copy and paste into the original post. 

For formatting to note that it is code, the answer posted here is a good resource: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: found the issue. the results its showing is 2 pages of lizards which is perfect as i have 2 lizard names per page. using pagination with a table. But when i click the 2 page it adds a page on at the beginning with snake data like it resets.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not fully clear, but perhaps you are looking for the `selected` attribute.

```html
<select name="species">
    <option value="Snake">Snake</option>
    <option value="Lizard" selected>Lizard</option>
</select>
```

with PHP you could do something like this:

```php
<?php
$selectedSpecies = $_POST['species'];
?>

<select name="species">
    <?php foreach (['Snake', 'Lizard'] as $species) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $species; ?>" <?= $species === $selectedSpecies ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?= $species; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: i was thinking that but i want options to be grabbed from the database not  preisiting one

Comment: okay i've added so far my option grab if you can see it :)

Comment: sure, it will still work, just look at the `<?= $species === $selectedSpecies ? 'selected' : ''; ?>` part and adapt it to your code

Comment: ah right the filtering works but with the select code you see above in my code example it when i click lizard it will show the results but say i have 2 pages if i click lizard, it will show the correct numbers. if however i click onto page 2 it will add another page before it with snake results and basically move the origional results to page 2 and 3 if that makes sense

Comment: is it possible to use $_post without reloading page?

Comment: $_POST is the data that is sent to the server to load the page, you cant change $_POST and the affects it has on the page without doing a full refresh. If you are looking to change the input elements dynamically without reloading the page then you'd have to look into using JavaScript to achieve that.

Comment: would you be able to point me in the direction for the javascript on what to kind of look for to achieve the results?